# Elastic Beanstalk without a web server on the EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a very specific requirement for which I'm trying to use Elastic Beanstalk where I do not require an internet facing web server.  The actual requirement is a little involved but boils down to needing a continuously running EC2 server which every 15mins uses wget or curl to pull a fairly large file from a private URL (other options have been looked at but for reasons outside my control this is the only way) where the transfer takes about 360s thus precluding the use of a CloudWatch-triggered Lambda function.

Since I don't want the hassle of managing the EC2 instance myself, I was looking at Elastic Beanstalk as a nice managed solution.  I have proven my solution works as required on Beanstalk (where I have configured a cron job in .ebextensions/ to invoke a small shell script to wget the file and then upload it to a S3 bucket). It doesn't need Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby, Go, Docker or any of the other platform options offered by Beanstalk, but Beanstalk is perfect for my particular use case.

The only thing is, it seems I get an Apache web server running on the EC2 whether I like it or not.  What are my options here for configuring Beanstalk so that no Apache process is started?

Comment: Is this a senario, where your EC2 pools a server on schedule to do a predefined job or, can there be many job instances at a single time?

Comment: Have you considered running this task inside of a Docker container?  You can then run (and schedule) that container on an ECS Cluster using _Scheduled Tasks_: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html

Comment: Have you looked at Beanstalk Worker Environments? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: @MarkB, thanks for the suggestion. I had a look at that page and while it does say it is suited for long-running tasks, it seems to me it revolves around having a separate job sending POST requests to a web server running my application. This is not what I want as my application is just a shell script and requires no web server. In fact everything runs just nicely the way I have it; all I'm seeking to do now is configure Beanstalk so that it does *not* give me a web server on the EC2 that it spins up to run my script. Please correct me if I have misunderstood what you are suggesting, thanks.

Comment: @user6831481 you can't run Elastic Beanstalk without a web server. Worker Environments are the closest thing in EB to what you are asking for. The web server in a worker environment isn't exposed, so it is secure. If you absolutely do not want a web server running on the server then EB isn't the right tool for the job and you probably need to look into ECS or some other AWS service.

Comment: @Ashan, thanks for the reply. The requirement here is for a single job instance at any given time. Every 15mins, it does a GET request to a private server (outside of AWS) and retrieves a large text file (which is only made available to me in an uncompressed format, and takes around 6mins to transfer).

Comment: @user6831481 If you need only one static instance, and are not interested in auto-scaling, your best solution is one plain old EC2 machine. There is nothing to configure, and it will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this now is to add a [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/python-configuration-procfile.html) to the application source directory, which lets you run a custom command to start the web application. For instance, inserting this command in the Procfile replaces the WSGI server with a celery worker.

```
web: celery -A app.celery_app worker -P gevent --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=5 --logfile=/var/log/celery.log --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair
```